# Store multiple chars in a long and recover them

Tags: c#, c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

The following code is used to compact multiple values in a long. The long is used as a key in a C++ unordered_map. It allows me to use the map with a number instead of a complex structure and ifs on each properties. The map searching to be as efficient as possible.

```
DWORD tmpNo = object->room->details->No;

unsigned char compactNo = tmpNo ;

unsigned __int16 smallX = object->x;
unsigned __int16 smallY = object->y;

unsigned __int64 longCode = 0;

longCode   =    (item->code[0] << 56) |
                (item->code[1] << 48) | 
                (item->code[2] << 40) | 
                (compactNo     << 32) |
                (smallX        << 24) |
                (smallY        <<  8);
```

Am I using the | operator correctly here ?

To recover the values, I tryed :

```
unsigned char c0    = key >> 56; 
unsigned char c1    = key >> 48; 
unsigned char c2    = key >> 40;
```

etc, but it didn't work.

Is it because the original item->code chars are chars and not unsigned chars (the values are always positive though) ?

Also, in an ideal world, the long's values would be recovered in a .NET DLL. Is it possible to do so in C# ?

Comment: `char` is a 16-bit type in C# - your code appears to think it's just 8 bits...

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Compilation error? Access violation? Wrong result?

Comment: @Dave, then you should update the question text and describe how it didn't work and what your expectation was.

Comment: `long` is not the same thing as `unsigned __int64`. A `long` in C++ is not guaranteed to be 64 bits, and often isn't.

Comment: Perhaps you want `(key >> 40) & 0xFF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has a `byte` type for an 8-bit value, but otherwise the logic is similar.

Your `|` logic looks fine (except you should be shifting `smallX` by 16 and `smallY` by 0)

Comment: Converting to unsigned char is equivalent to masking with 0xff, surely?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you gave a complete example.

But assuming that `item->code[0]` is a char or int (signed or unsigned), you need to convert it to a 64 bit type before shifting, otherwise you end up with undefined behaviour, and the wrong answer.

Something like

```
((unsigned __int64) item->code[0]) << 56
```

should work better.

Answer (score 1):

I think that **stdint.h** is very useful to understand this kind of implementation (sized integers are very meaningful). So here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int8_t getValue8(int index, uint64_t container) {
    return (uint8_t)((container >> (index * 8)) & 0XFF);
}

void setValue8(int index, uint64_t* container, uint8_t value) {
    // get left part of container including the last byte (cleared by ~0xFF mask) to be used by value
    int shift = index * 8;
    uint64_t mask = (uint64_t) ~0xFF;
    uint64_t left = (*container >> shift) & mask;
    left = (left | value) << shift;

    // right part of container (complement)
    mask = ((uint64_t)1 << ++shift) - 1;
    uint64_t right = *container & mask;

    // update container
    *container = left | right;
}

int main() {
    uint64_t* container;    // container: can contain 8 chars (64-bit sized container)
    uint64_t containerValue = 0;
    int n = 8;              // n value must be <= 8 considering a 64-bit sized container
    uint8_t chars[n];       // eight char values to be stored

    // add/set values to container
    container = &containerValue;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        chars[i] = (uint8_t)((i+1)*10);
        setValue8(i, container, chars[i]);
        printf("setValue8(%d, container, %d)\n", i, chars[i]);
    }

    // get values from container
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("getValue8(%d, container)=%d\n", i, getValue8(i, *container));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code use only bit masks and some bitwise operations, and so you can easily port it to C#. If you have any questions about it just ask. I hope I have been helpful.